# dask printing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dask

I am trying to get same print output as just calling x,
I tried several options:

```
import dask.array as da
x = da.random.random(size=(1000, 20), chunks=(20, 5))
print(str(x))
print(repr(x))
x


print(x)
print(x.__print__())
print(x.__str__())
print(str(x))
print(repr(x))
```

nothing works, any ideas what jupyter uses for printing?
[image]

Comment: don't post your code in picture format..., post your code in jupyter in a code block.

Comment: I had to show the visualization of the output

Comment: post your output but post your code in code block

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are interested in `._repr_html_()` method.

```py
import dask.array as da
from IPython.core.display import HTML

x = da.random.random(size=(1000, 20), chunks=(20, 5))
HTML(x._repr_html_())
```